# Angular 6 Material retreive material colors

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material2

"@angular/material": "^6.2.1"
Got quite stuck with a very minor issue.
Can't import any standard material color in any of my app's css/scss files, including `styles.scss`

example:

`$app-panel-green: mat-color($mat-green);`

gives this error in any scss file:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed: 
$app-panel-green: mat-color($mat-green);
                           ^
      Undefined variable: "$mat-green".
      in /**********/src/styles.scss (line 1, column 29)
```

styles.scss consits only of (except previous):

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
/*@import './theme.scss';*/

body { margin: 0; }
```

and pre-built theme works just fine. 
I don't even need a custom theme, just want to use material color palette.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use one of default palettes, you can do it like this:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming'; // Pay attention on the path
@include mat-core();
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-deep-orange, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

And don't forget to include the file with your theming to `.angular-cli.json` to `styles` section.

Comment: but i want to use a default theme. this will change it to custom, right?

Comment: also just did this - same error on colors import.for example  `color: mat-color($mat-deep-purple);` -> `Undefined variable: "$mat-deep-purple"`

Comment: @user1935987 to activate the default brebuilt theme you just need to import it: `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` and include this file to `.angular-cli.json` to `styles` section. Check this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrhetd?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: yes i did this weeks ago :). the question is not how to setup a custom theme, but about the problem with using material color palette. "Can't import any standard material color in any of my app's css/scss"

Comment: @user1935987, try to remove tilde from path

Comment: tried - import doesn't work then. Again, it's not a problem with themes - they are working (including custom theme sample provided by you). The problem is that i can't use angular material scss variables in my application(i.e `$mat-deep-purple`)

Comment: @user1935987, what's the path to your file, where you're trying to import variables? `src/styles.scss`?

Comment: @user1935987, try to import the variables like this: `@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss';`

Comment: `'~@angular/material/theming'` is imported and i can use it, but only in `theme.scss`

Comment: @user1935987 What's your version of Angular Material?

Comment: I'm using the older one, but I googled about the latest